# Constructing a function that returns two distinct values by Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, parametric-functions

I'm trying to enter a function in Mathematica that can take two inputs, a, and b, and return two outcomes based on those two numbers.

I will assume the name of this function as

Resultsf[a _,b _]

the inputs are :

x1=a;
x2=b;

The two operations which I would like Mathematica to do are :

f1=x1+x2;
f2=x1*x2;

Here are the two results that I anticipated from the function Resultsf[a _,b _]

input Resultsf[3,3]
output 6

```
   9
```

what is the sequence of such kind of program?
Regards

Comment: You can use `List` or `{}` to return multiple values. In your case it would be `Resultsf[a_, b_] := {a+b, a*b}`.

Comment: As @BenIzd said, return a list, then you can display the list in any desired manner. For example, `Results[3, 3] // Column` or `{Results[3, 3]} //  Grid`

Answer (score 3):

Using `Apply` and `Function`:

```
Resultsf[{a_, b_}] := Apply[Function[{x, y}, {x + y, x*y}], {a, b}]
```

Test using Syed's example:

```
Resultsf[#] & /@ {{-4, -1}, {-5, 2}, {-5, -5}, {3, 1}, {-5, -1}}
(*{{-5, 4}, {-3, -10}, {-10, 25}, {4, 3}, {-6, 5}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[alist]
SeedRandom[1];

alist = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {5, 2}]
```

> {{-4, -1}, {-5, 2}, {-5, -5}, {3, 1}, {-5, -1}}

```
Through[{Plus, Times}[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ alist
```

OR

```
{Plus @@ #, Times @@ #} & /@ alist
```

---

Result:

> {{-5, 4}, {-3, -10}, {-10, 25}, {4, 3}, {-6, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental data structure in Mathematica is the List. If you want to put two things together, you put them into a list. So, `Resultsf` should probably return a list:

```
Resultsf[a_, b_] := {f1[a, b], f2[a, b]}
```

Try it out:

```
Resultsf[x, y]
```

`{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}`

That's probably the easiest to understand way to do it. But there is a bit of repetition, specifically we had to "mention" a and b twice each. Mathematica has a built in function to deal with exactly this situation: multiple functions applied to the same arguments. It's called Through:

```
AlternateResultsf[a_, b_] := Through[{f1, f2}[a, b]]
```

Try this one out:

```
AlternateResultsf[x, y]
```

`{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}`

To make this concrete, we'll use the multiplication and addition that you gave in your example:

```
AlternateResultsf[a_, b_] := Through[{Plus, Times}[a, b]]
```

And giving it a go:

```
AlternateResultsf[x, y]
```

`{x + y, x y}`

Or, going back to the first implementation:

```
Resultsf[a_, b_] := {a + b, a*b}
```

And now we have

```
Resultsf[x, y]
```

`{x + y, x y}`

Answer (score 1):

Using  `Query` :

```
list = {{-4, -1}, {-5, 2}, {-5, -5}, {3, 1}, {-5, -1}};

Query[All, Apply /@ {Plus, Times}] @ list
```

{{-5, 4}, {-3, -10}, {-10, 25}, {4, 3}, {-6, 5}}